# How to find out the date the OS was installed?

Tags: windows-7, installation

Is there a way that I can get the date that the current OS (for example, Windows 7) was installed?

Answer (score 3):

## Command prompt

1. Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   wmic os get installdate
   ```

### Remarks

- Works regardless of the system locale.
- The value is in is displayed in the UTC format and is not affected by changes in time zone or daylight saving time.

### Example output

```
InstallDate
20140519224731.000000+120
```

The format is `yyyyMMddHHmmss`. Anything after the period represents the number of milliseconds, which can be safely ignored. The value is parsed this way:

- `2014` year
- `05` month
- `19` day
- `22` hour
- `47` minutes
- `31` seconds

---

## PowerShell

Assuming it's available, you can run the following commands:

```
$os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
$os.ConvertToDateTime($os.InstallDate)
```

### Example output

```
Monday, May 19, 2014 10:47:31 PM
```

Comment: it is a bit difficult to read.

Comment: @Devid Added further information, and an alternate solution.

Comment: Yep, I seen it so I gave +1

Answer (score 2):

Start the command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> "cmd" -> press return)
Enter the following command:

```
cmd /k systeminfo | find "Original Install Date"
```

P.S. I found the information [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/167466-date-time-windows-installation-find.html).

**EDIT:** The following [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) command works for Windows installations with locales other than English.

Start PowerShell (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> "powershell" -> press return)
Enter the following command:

```
([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate)
```

P.S. I got the info from [here](http://www.sepago.de/d/helge/2009/09/24/how-to-determine-the-windows-installation-date-with-and-without-powershell).

Answer (score 1):

For windows 7
Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
or click start and then run

type cmd and press enter to start command prompt.
Inside command prompt, type

```
systeminfo | find "Install Date"
```

and press enter, after a few seconds, you should get install date.

For Windows XP it's simpler, simply go to C: and right click on WINDOWS
folder and select properties, and look at date the folder was created.

Comment: The command won't work on non-English systems.